# How to generate sitemap for already developed struts 1.2 web application?

Tags: java, user-interface, struts, sitemap

I have an already developed web application based on struts 1.2 which contains jsp pages with hyperlinks to other pages. Is there a sitemap generator tool available that can browse through my web app and based on hyperlinks give me a sitemap (in xml, if possible).
or if there's any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider parsing the Struts 1 config files and building the map that way, depending on your actual needs. For example, if you view pages based on a URL parameter, this might not be as convenient. For straight-forward mapping, though, this technique is valuable for both internal and external documentation.

There are also a ton of online map generators that will crawl your site for you, although some charge once you cross a threshold number of pages.

You can also check out [this page of sitemap generators](http://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/wiki/SitemapGenerators) that includes a hefty list of tools.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will check them out.